# Embedding dendrogram in Java

Tags: java, graphics, dendrogram

I'm looking for a library capable of drawing [dendrograms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dendrogram) of data in Java (not calculating them, I can do it by myself).. do you have any clues? Already tried to search it over Google but haven't found anything that is not stand-alone (while I need to embed the generation inside my program).

Thanks!

Comment: Was wondering if you found a solution?

Comment: Yes, I did it with Jung :) Quite easy to use and powerful at the same time!

Comment: could you elaborate a bit on how you managed to do it with Jung? Which layout for instance?

Comment: Were you able to draw a dendrogram with JUNG2 ? If yes, how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/) graph library.  It won't perform the actual clustering for you but is a really good library for visualising your results.

Comment: thanks, I don't need anything that calculates.. I already wrote what I need, just needed something to draw results :D I'll check in a while and accept it if it's good! (I think it is from a quick look)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Archaeopteryx](http://www.phylosoft.org/archaeopteryx/).  It has fairly many features; it's open source, and it is available in a pre-packaged jar file.

BTW, I use JUNG and really like it.  It can perform various clusterings, but AFAIK, it has no inherent dendrogram capabilities.  Because it has graphing capabilities, you could roll your own dendrogram, but it would take some work.